# Some applications are being displayed half cut down on my wide screen monitor

Tags: display, resolution

I have 20-inch Samsung LCD.  Some application are displayed  half on the screen.  There is nothing wrong with the LCD or any other hardware. Every thing else is working fine.

However some software appears half on the screen.  I have tried changing the resolution of the screen.  I have checked that software on another computer having CRT monitor, and it's working fine. 
I have pasted a snapshot below.

[image: Snapshot]